# Why does this formula always give me $0$ modulo $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mu(n)$ be the Moebius function.  Let $a$ be a positive integer.  For odd $n$ (this is possibly true for all $n$, but I only care for odd ones) I get that
$$\sum_{d|n} \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) a^d \equiv 0 \pmod n.$$
Is there a nice reason for this that can be seen purely from the formula?  I have a proof for some special cases of $a$ that uses the particular features of the way I got it, but it would be nice to just be able to see it from the formula.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done through basic application of CRT; for each prime power factor $p^e$ of $n$, pair off terms in the sum that are $p$-multiples of each other.

Comment: If you'd like to see this done by brute force, see Chapter 4.9 in <i>Concrete Mathematics</i>.

Comment: See https://mattbaker.blog/2020/05/26/generalizations-of-fermats-little-theorem-and-combinatorial-zeta-functions/

Comment: This congruence is often called "Gauss's congruence" so presumably (though not necessarily) it's due to Gauss. Various references can be found in Heinrich Steinlein, *Fermat's little theorem and Gauss congruence: matrix versions and cyclic permutations,*" Amer. Math. Monthly 124 (2017), no. 6, 548–553.

Comment: I suspect the connection with Gauss is as follows. For $a$ being a prime number, your expression divided by $n$ is the number of irreducible monic polynomials of degree $n$ over the finite field $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ (which implies your congruence in a special case). The formula for the number of irreducible is due to Gauss, and it is not too far off from similar formulas in Riemann's famous paper on the prime number conjecture (now theorem). By the way, one can construct an explicit bijection from the necklaces described by Alon Amit and irreducible polynomials.

Comment: @IraGessel  it is due to Gauss when $a = p$ is prime (counting monic irreducibles of degree $n$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$) as part of the unpublished (originally) section VIII of the *Disquisitiones*.  See the third page of Cox's article https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Cox-2012.pdf.

Comment: One of your department colleagues wrote a short paper explaining this congruence relation: see L. Levine, "Fermat's Little Theorem: A Proof by Function Iteration",
Mathematics Magazine 72 (1999), 308-309. And the congruence remains true with $\mu(n/d)$ replaced by $\varphi(n/d)$, as first proved by MacMahon in the 1890s. For a more recent proof of that, see I. M. Isaacs and M. R. Pournaki, “Generalizations of Fermat’s Little Theorem Using Group Theory,” Amer. Math. Monthly 112 (2005), 734–740.

Comment: The early history of this congruence is discussed in Dickson's History of the Theory of Numbers, volume 1, pages 84 to 86 (https://archive.org/details/historyoftheoryo01dick).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your expression, divided by $n$, is the number of aperiodic necklaces of length $n$ with $a$ colors. Since this number is an integer, the sum must be divisible by $n$.

See *Aperiodic necklaces* [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly what I was looking for.